# unique key indexing for multiple columns in mongodb using morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

**In a serialized model**  i have **3 columns** `String name,String phone no, int door No.`
i want all the three this to be an unique key index. in MySQL we would do something like this.

```
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE ID ` (`NAME`,`PHONE NO`,`DOOR NO`)
```

how to do the same thing for mongodb using morphia. i tried with

```
@Indexes({@Index("name, phone no,door No,")})


 @Entity
@Indexes({@Index(value="name, phone no,door No", unique = true)})
```

but it doesn't seem to work please help.

Comment: Are you sure the spaces in your attribute names ``phone no`` and ``door No`` are ok? If you haven't rewritten the names via ``@Property("xxx")`` they need to be the same as your Java class members. The ``@Indexes(...)`` should be fine otherwise. And what specifically is the problem of "it doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: their are no spaces , stack overflow was not allowing to provided spaces and post the question. even just @indexed(unique=true) is also not working should i extend any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no indexes are being created at all, you're most likely missing the `datastore.ensureIndexes()`, see https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Datastore#Ensure_Indexes_and_Caps